# Add user on UrBackup server after order on Woocommerce site

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have wordpress site with woocommerce shop and I’m selling among others UrBackup client accounts on my server. 
Do you have any idea how to automatically add UrBackup user after order in woocommerce?
Or maybe easier will be create shop based on different engine?
Any advice, tips? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After poking around a bit, it looks like UrBackup has an API you can use, that most likely has a 'create account' endpoint. I didn't see it immediately in their not-so-great documentation, but you'd think it'd HAVE to be there somewhere! There's also a PHP API kit you could integrate into your WordPress site here:

https://bitbucket.org/opensaucesystemsdevelopment/urbackup-api.git

So, you could load in this class, and after a WooCommerce order is placed, call the API endpoint to create a user. To do this with WooCommerce, you'd need to create a function on the "woocommerce_order_status_completed" hook.

http://hookr.io/actions/woocommerce_order_status_completed/

This would let you run any custom code you'd like after an order's payment has completed. Thus, you could check an order for if it contains the UrBackup product, and if so call the UrBackup API to create an account based on the current user's data.

Should work!